# how to detemine the type of actual object without using typeid/RTTI

Tags: inheritance

I have a class hiearchy, in which child classes derive from parents..

At one place, I need to store (queue) objects of any type into a list, list[Parent*], and later retrieve objects from that list. When storing, I store pointers, which points to the top-most parent class. When retrieving, I need to understand which child object it is actually, to be able to correctly use it by down-casting.

The straightforward method may be to use dynamic_cast and check if it returns 0 or not. But, I know (if I am not wrong) that would mean using RTTI.

How would you achieve this, without using RTTI ? Inserting a mType field in the parent class, and letting any child class to assign a specific type info for this field, and then check its value (to see what is the type) whenever needed ? But this seems to be a cumbersome method, doesn't it ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: The second method you described is indeed cumbersome, that is why RTTI is there in the first place. This is the way to go, but lets see if someone gives a better solution.

Comment: In software requirements, one principle is to ask the customer what he/she needs rather than what he/she wants. So what do you exactly need? Do you really need to cast the object? Can't you solve your problem by using virtual functions / polymorhism?