# Object type detection in hierarchy

Tags: c++, oop, hierarchy

I've got a hierarchy of game objects:

```
class GameObject {
public:
    virtual void update(float dt) = 0;
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};
class Building : public GameObject {}
class Sawmill : public Building {}
class Human : public GameObject {}
```

and so on. All objects are managed by the game (which is not a subclass of GameObject :). The game stores all the objects in std::vector<GameObject *> and successfully invokes virtual methods such as update and draw, that's all good. But sometimes I need to detect what type of GameObject I'm dealing with. For this case we've came up with a solution: GameObject has a enum of GameObject types and each GameObject subclass returns his own value from this enum.

```
class GameObject {
public:
    enum GOType
    {
        GOGameObject,
        GOBuilding,
        GOSawmill,
        GOHuman,
        ...
    }
    static GOType Type() { return GOGameObject; }
    virtual GOType getType() const { return GameObject::Type(); }
};

class Building : public GameObject {
public:
    static GOType Type() { return GOBuilding; }
    virtual GOType getType() const { return Building::Type(); }
};
```

So, every subclass of GameObject has it's own version of "static GOType Type()" method which returns a value from enum GOType. And it has overloaded virtual method "GOType getType() const" which just calls it's own class method Type(). Anywhere in game I can check if the object I have a pointer to is, for example, a Building:

```
if (obj && obj->getType() == Building::Type()) {
    // then do stuff
}
```

To make it clear - this solution works fine and has proven itself to be extensible and very efficient (the first solution we've came up with was returning strings in getType() and comparing them; it was veeery slow).

The only downside I see is that I have to extend GOType in GameObject every time I add a new GameObject subclass. Now it contains about a hundred of types and it doesn't look and feel beautiful (I'm beeing a perfectionist here :)

So, my question is: is there any other solution of the problem which is as efficient as this one but without necessity of extending GOType in GameObject?

Comment: What goes in `// then do stuff`? Depending on that, you can get much much much better solutions. (http://www.antiifcampaign.com/)

Comment: "sometimes I need to detect what type of GameObject I'm dealing with" - this is likely a fault in your design. If you are frequently checking types then you are not programming in an object-oriented fashion despite using classes. For reacting differently to different types use [double dispatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: Very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123042/how-to-detemine-the-type-of-actual-object-without-using-typeid-rtti

Comment: @TamásSzelei believe me, using enum to detect actual object type is one of the most beautiful design solutions in this project :) everything else is much much worse. btw, thanks for the link, i'll check it out

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a huge chain of inherited classes, why don't you template your `draw` and `update` function so you can pass in any `T` and it will do whatever you need.  If you need to have different behaviors for a specific `T` you can specialize.

Just a suggestion.

Comment: Didn't get exactly what you mean. Can you provide some code to illustrate what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic_cast`.

```
if ( dynamic_cast<Building*>(obj) ) 
{
    // then do stuff
}
```

There will be no need for an `enum` or a `getType()` method.

Comment: @Firedragon: As if anybody is colossally stupid enough to compile their code with a core language feature missing.

Comment: @DeadMG - We don't use RTTI in the project for some historical reasons – dimayak 32 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that is you need to know what they type is at run time then maybe there is a problem with the design. If you are calling your "Do stuff" on the objects then use of virtual functions and polymorphism would mean you do not need to know what the object is.

But that said if you have RTTI enabled then that would seem to be a way to determine what types objects are at run time without needing to add they type into the base class.

[`typeid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid) can be used to determine the type at run time.

Comment: We don't use RTTI in the project for some historical reasons

Comment: @dimayak Without RTTI you cannot use `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` so detecting at run time I suspect needs the way you have it in your code (unless a person more knowledgeable than me can suggest a way) but as I and others have said, there are ways to use polymorphism so you don't need to know what the type is

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic_cast:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cby9kycs%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

You'll find some examples in the link.